# WPF Expander - Highlight Header on mouse over

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an ItemsControl where the datatemplate is an expander.  Below is the template and style used for the exapnder's header.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="expanderHeader">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" TextBlock.Foreground="Blue"/>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        </Trigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>

<Style TargetType="Expander">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource expanderHeader}"/>
</Style>
```

The header is bolded when the mouse moves over the actual header text, but what i want is the header text to be bolded if i the mouse is over any part of the expander.  To fix this i think i need to move the trigger to the expander style itself, but here i am not sure how to ensure only the header and not all contents within the expander are bolded, which is what happens when i use the following style:

```
    <Style TargetType="Expander">
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource expanderHeader}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>           
    </Style>
```

How can i tweak the above so that only the header text is bolded when thenouse is moved over the any part of the expander (when expanded ofcourse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution I could come up with was to create a second DataTemplate to switch to on mouse over.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="expanderHeader">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" TextBlock.Foreground="Blue"/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="expanderHeaderMouseOver">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" TextBlock.Foreground="Blue" TextElement.FontWeight="Bold"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

And then change the style of the expander to set that HeaderTemplate on mouse over...

```
<Style TargetType="Expander">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource expanderHeader}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource expanderHeaderMouseOver}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Obviously this means you'll need to maintain 2 data templates, which isn't really ideal... There's probably a better solution out there (maybe using attached properties) but I couldn't get anything else to work.

Comment: Thanks much. I think that's a fine solution and works for me.